# Binary Search Tree Balancing

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search

I had a quesiton here, but it didn't save. I'm having trouble balancing a fully unbalanced tree (nodes 1-15 along the right side).

I'm having trouble because I get stack overflow.

```
> // balancing
    public void balance(node n) {
        if(n != null) {
            System.out.println(height(n)-levels);
            if (height(n.RCN) != height(n.LCN)) {
                if (height(n.RCN) > height(n.LCN)) {
                    if(height(n.RCN) > height(n.LCN)) {
                        n = rotateL(n);
                        n = rotateR(n);
                    } else {
                        n = rotateL(n);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(height(n.LCN) > height(n.RCN)) {
                        n = rotateR(n);
                        n = rotateL(n);
                    } else {
                        n = rotateR(n);
                    }
                }
                balance(n.LCN);
                balance(n.RCN);
            }
        }
    }

    // depth from node to left
    public int heightL(node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return 0;
        return height(n.LCN) + 1;
    }

    // depth from node from the right
    public int heightR(node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return 0;
        return height(n.RCN) + 1;
    }

    // left rotation around node
    public node rotateL(node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return null;
        else {
            node newRoot = n.RCN;
            n.RCN = newRoot.LCN;
            newRoot.LCN = n;
            return newRoot;
        }
    }

    // right rotation around node
    public node rotateR(node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return null;
        else {
            node newRoot = n.LCN;
            n.LCN = newRoot.RCN;
            newRoot.RCN = n;
            return newRoot;
        }
    }
```

Comment: obligatory comment: huh? what is your question?

Comment: I thought I had edited this with my quesiton, but it didn't save. My fault.

Basically, I'm getting a stack overflow because I have an incorrect algorithm. I have the right idea, but I'm not able to implement. I think the trouble is that I need to balance from the root until the two sides are equal or differ by 1 if n is even, then proceed down the left node and balance it recursively, and then onto the right node of the root.

Comment: I also noticed that there seems to be an error occurring because of null values (perhaps n.left is null, so I get an error), but I put an "else return" and that stopped the error, and it displayed that there is pretty much no shifting occurring.

Comment: People are too quick to close at times. They didn't even give you time to fix your mistake. Wow. I'll vote to reopen and hopefully others will do the same.

Comment: Btw, I don't see the implementation for `height`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `rotateL` followed by a `rotateR` ends up doing nothing since you are modifying the same node. `n` is not the original `n`.  It is the `newNode` from the function. So basically, `n` is something like this:

```
newNode = rotateL(n);
n = rotateR(newNode);
```

So you are basically leaving the tree unchanged.

I am also unsure as to why you repeat the `if (height(n.RCN) > height(n.LCN))` check. I think you meant your first check to be more like `abs(height(n.RCN) - height(n.LCN)) > 1` and then use the comparison to determine which way to rotate.

Also, could you add the implementation for `height(...)`?